# bucket.blob.upload_from_string returns "ValueError: None could not be converted to unicode"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a DataFrame (`df`) to cloud storage using the following line of code:

```
bucket.blob(gcs_reference).upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8'), content_type=''application/octet-stream')
```

However, my DataFrame has for some cells None values and therefore it triggers the error:

> ValueError: None could not be converted to unicode

Is there a way to surpress this and just put empty values for the None? I did not had any issues with this in the past, I cannot recall what I did different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce and it worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from gcloud import storage
client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('source')
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

bucket.blob('file').upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8'), 
content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

The content of file is :

```
col1,col2
1,3.0
2,
```

Or you can use:

```
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
bucket.blob('file').upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False, 
encoding='utf-8'), content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

And the output file would be:

```
col1,col2
1,3.0
2,0.0
```

In your code is this part:

```
 content_type=''application/octet-stream'
```

It is a syntax error there

> content_type=''application/octet-stream'

Comment: Ideally I would not want to fill the nones but really have them as empty values

Comment: Also with None?

Comment: Yes , the example is a df with None